# How to use elasticsearch-entity-resolution plugin from c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, named-entity-extraction

I am new in elastic search. I need to implement entity extraction in my ES. I planned to use the plugin elasticsearch-entity-resolution(duke's). How can I use it in my c# code.Can anyone please help?